# Monitoring Windows TaskBar statechange using win32

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

**Environment:**

Windows 7

Visual Studio (2008) C++ (No .NET)

**Short and sweet goal:**

Ensure the Windows Taskbar is never visible.

**Details:**

I'd like to be able to register for the Window's event [ABN_STATECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#tbnotify_Taskbar_Display_Options), and if the event is triggered, disable and hide the taskbar.

I can do the latter pretty easily:

```
CWnd *Wnd;
Wnd = CWnd::FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);

Wnd -> ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
Wnd -> EnableWindow(false);
```

However I'm not sure how to capture the taskbar statechange event using win32.  Note-- I cannot use the .NET framework. Should I do this via a CALLBACK WindowProc?  I really don't know where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Applications need to allow the user to access the taskbar. Otherwise the user is trapped.

Comment: Yes, the intent is to keep the users from getting to the taskbar and trapping them.  We are working in a fairly unique environment, and the user should be locked into our application until the application closes.

Comment: Sorry, the taskbar does not support the ability to do this because it has the principle that it is always available. If this is a special-purpose system, you can use an alternate shell entirely. If you choose to do something unsupported, make sure your client understands that it may stop working at any time. (e.g. a security hot fix may break it.)

Answer (score 0):

This notification is sent to [appbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177.aspx). You register as one by calling [`SHAppBarMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108.aspx) with `ABM_NEW` option.

Comment: Hmm okay-- after reading more about the appbars, it appears this isn't the same as the Windows Taskbar, is that correct?  Is there a Windows Event to track the Windows Taskbar's visibility?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Windows Event. Appbars are notified of the taskbar's position and appearance, because they often need to coordinate with each other. If you want those notifications, you need to register your window as an appbar (it doesn't have to actually be visible). I'm not aware of any other source of this information.

Comment: I think we are talking about two different things.  It says on the MSDN that:
An application desktop toolbar (also called an appbar) is a window that is similar to the Windows taskbar. 
I think we are talking about two different things.  I want to be able to keep the Windows Taskbar from automatically reappearing by detecting a Windows Event informing the system that the taskbar has appeared and make it go away agian.

Comment: An application desktop toolbar (also called an appbar) is notified by Windows, in the form of `ABN_STATECHANGE` notification, whenever the Windows Taskbar's autohide or always-on-top state has changed. Is this not what you want to be notified about?

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools that allow you to replace the windows shell.  You might be able to figure out how those applications work.
[You can see a list of alternative windows shells here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows)

From what I've seen, they replace explorer.exe with their own executable.
You might be able to kill explorer.exe on launch of your application and then restore it after the application exits.

Additionally, you can lock out more savy users by placing a monitor in your application which watches for the start up of explorer.exe and kills it. You'd have to deal with other security loop holes such as accessing the TaskManager or command prompt.

**This is a dangerous approach, if your application crashes the system could become unusable and may require a hard power cycle to restore it.**

**Alternatively** you could make your application a full screen application and have it lock out functions like alt tab and the windows key.
You can do this simply by settings your main window's WindowState to maximized, TopMost to true and WindowStyle to none. Then handling key presses at a low level.
This will cover your windows task bar and prevent the user from accessing it until they exit the application.